# Request failed with status code 401 axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, axios

i am creating a signup page with react using axios and i get Request failed with status code 401

```
    let { data } = await axios.post(
      "https://route-ecommerce.onrender.com/api/v1/auth/signup",
      values
    );
    console.log(data);
```

i searched a lot and did not get anything

#react #javascript #axios

Comment: 401 indicates you are missing authentication headers. Pass in the appropriate headers that your backend expects

Comment: The 401 status code of a response indicates that the request wasn’t successful because it lacks valid authentication credentials. So if there is a message with the response in question please add. Although I don’t see how the backend would be requiring authorization for a signup request. You probably want to check in with the backend if so.

Comment: The 401 status code of a response indicates that the request wasn’t successful because it lacks valid authentication credentials.

Answer (score 0):

This error message means the request you made to the server requires authentication authorization.
First, you can verify the API endpoint, then check the request headers and handle Cors.